# d3js enter, update, exit confusion: need assistance please

Tags: d3.js, meteor

I genuinely hate to ask this question, particularly as I know it has been asked dozens of times - and I've read through the posts. But my problem remains - I simply do not understand how this mechanism works. I am new to d3js, and am using **v3.x** in meteor; I've gone through tutorials and have gotten something working, but can't get it to update with new data. Again, my apologies for rehashing this, but none of the other posts I've read has resolved the issue.

Here is a code fragment, I've stripped out all the stuff that shouldn't make a difference to focus on the core functionality:

```
var w = 800;
var h = 800;
var intensity = 25;
var margin = {
    top: 75,
    right: 100,
    bottom: 75,
    left: 60
};

var svg = d3.select('#heatmap')
    .append('svg')
    .attr('width', w + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr('height', h + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append('g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')');

// get csv data, x & y coords, etc...

createHeatmap = function(csv, x, y) {
    var data = d3.csv.parseRows(csv).map(function(row) {
        return row.map(function(d) {
            return +d;
        });
    });

    // set some values
    var min = 0;
    var max = d3.max(data, function(d, i) {
        return i + 1;
    });
    var rectSize = 4;

    // set the scales for both axes
    ...

    // set up the axes
    ...

    // define colorScale
    ...

    // create heatmap
    svg.selectAll('g')
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append('g')
        .selectAll('rect')
        .data(function(d, i, j) {
            return d;
        })
        .enter() // start drawing rects
        .append('rect')
        .attr('x', function(d, i, j) {
            return (i * rectSize);
        })
        .attr('y', function(d, i, j) {
            return (j * rectSize);
        })
        .attr('width', w / max)
        .attr('height', h / max)
        .style('fill', function(d, i, j) {
            return colorScale(d * intensity);
        });

    // append axes, scales, labels, etc.
}

// create heatmap
createHeatmap(csv, x, y);
```

My problem is that I do not understand why the chart doesn't update the heatmap when I pass new data into createHeatmap().

I stepped through it in the debugger and everything works as I would expect during the initial creation of the heatmap, which renders correctly. When I send new data is when the mystery starts. The debugger shows, deep within d3js itself (not in my code) that the enter() has an array full od null values instead of the data I am passing in. The data exists up until that point. So, as d3js processes the null data it naturally returns an empty object so no update occurs.

Obviously I am not doing the update correctly but am clueless about what I need to do to correct it.

Any advise is greatly appreciated.

Thx!

**Update:**
Andrew, thanks for the response. I tried your first suggestion, modifying your example to fit my data, but it doesn't update with new data.

My changes:

```
    var w = 800;
    var h = 800;
    var intensity = 25;
    var margin = {
        top: 75,
        right: 100,
        bottom: 75,
        left: 60
    };

    var svg = d3.select('#heatmap')
        .append('svg')
        .attr('width', w + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr('height', h + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append('g')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')');

    // get csv data, x & y coords, etc...

    createHeatmap = function(csv, x, y) {
        var data = d3.csv.parseRows(csv).map(function(row) {
            return row.map(function(d) {
                return +d;
            });
        });

        // set some values
        var min = 0;
        var max = d3.max(data, function(d, i) {
            return i + 1;
        });
        var rectSize = 4;

        // set the scales for both axes
        ...

        // set up the axes
        ...

        // define colorScale
        ...    

        // append group of svg elements bound to data
        var rows = svg.selectAll('g')
            .data(data);

        // enter new rows where needed
        rows.enter().append('g');

        // select all rects
        var rects = rows.selectAll('rect')
            .data(function(d, i, j) {
                return d;
            });

        // enter new rects:
        rects.enter().append('rect')
            .attr('x', function(d, i, j) {
                return (i * rectSize);
            })
            .attr('y', function(d, i, j) {
                return (j * rectSize);
            })
            .attr('width', w / max)
            .attr('height', h / max)
            .style('fill', function(d, i, j) {
                return colorScale(d * intensity);
            });
```

Added snippet:

```js
var csv = "'3, 6, 0, 8'\n'1, 9, 0, 4'\n'3, 0, 1, 8'\n'4, 0, 2, 7";
csv = csv.replace(/'/g,'');

var button = d3.select('button')
    .on('click', function() {
        createHeatmap(update());
    });

var w = 120;
var h = 120;
var intensity = 10;
var margin = {
    top: 25,
    right: 25,
    bottom: 25,
    left: 25
};

var svg = d3.select('#heatmap')
    .append('svg')
    .attr('width', w + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr('height', h + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append('g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')');

createHeatmap(csv); 

function createHeatmap(csv) {
    console.log(csv);
    var data = d3.csv.parseRows(csv).map(function(row) {
        return row.map(function(d) {
            return +d;
        });
    });

    var min = 0;
    var max = d3.max(data, function(d, i) {
        return i + 1;
    });
    var rectSize = 30;

    // define a colorScale with domain and color range
    var colorScale = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0,0.5,1])
        .range(['red', 'green', 'blue']);

    // append group of svg elements bound to data
    var rows = svg.selectAll('g')
        .data(data);

    // enter new rows where needed
    rows.enter().append('g');

    // select all rects
    var rects = rows.selectAll('rect')
        .data(function(d, i, j) {
            return d;
        });

    // enter new rects:
    rects.enter().append('rect')
        .attr('x', function(d, i, j) {
            return (i * rectSize);
        })
        .attr('y', function(d, i, j) {
            return (j * rectSize);
        })
        .attr('width', w / max)
        .attr('height', h / max)
        .style('fill', function(d, i, j) {
            return colorScale(d * intensity);
        });
}

function update() {
    var data = "'0, 1, 9, 5'\n'4, 0, 7, 2'\n'6, 3, 0, 8'\n'5, 3, 7, 0";
    data = data.replace(/'/g,'');
    return data;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js"></script>
<button>Update</button>
<div id="heatmap"></div>
```

Comment: You tagged the question with Meteor, so you may show the template or component code because rendering with external libraries require certain things to consider in Meteor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is in your method chaining.

On first run, things should run as expected:

```
// create heatmap
svg.selectAll('g')  // 1. select all g elements
 .data(data)        // 2. assign data
 .enter()           // 3. enter and append a g for each item in the data array 
 .append('g')       //    that doesn't have a corresponding element in the DOM (or more accurately, the selection)                     
 .selectAll('rect') // 4. For each newly entered g, select child rectangles
 .data(function(d, i, j) { // 5. assign data to child selection.
    return d;
 })
 .enter()            // 6. Enter and append a rect for each item in the child g's data array 
 .append("rect")     //    that doesn't have a corresponding element in the DOM.
 ....                // 7. Style
```

On that first run, we select all the `g`s, there are none, so the enter selection will have an element for each item in the data array: we are entering everything. Same as with the child rectangles: there are no child rectangles existing when you make the selection, so you enter everything in the child data array.

On the second run, with `svg.selectAll("g")`, you select all the `g`s you created the first time around - there is no need to enter anything if the data array has the same number of items. You don't want to append anything: `enter().append()` the second time (not that you are appending more elements with .append() in any event).

Essentially on the second pass you are modifying an empty selection.

Instead you want to update. While the enter selection is empty on the second pass, the update selection has all the existing `g`s.

There are a few methods to do this, one is to break your chaining:

*This is a version 3 solution:*

```
var rows = svg.selectAll("g")
    .data(data);

// enter new rows where needed
rows.enter().append("g")

// Select all rects
var rects = rows.selectAll("rect")
  .data(function(d) { return d; })

// Enter new rects:
rects.enter().append("rect")

// Update rects (all rects, not just the newly entered):
rects.attr()...
```

The below snippet uses this pattern, it enters new `rect`s and `g`s as needed. And then updates all the `rect`s and `g`s afterwards. *This takes advantage of a magic in d3v3, where the update selection and the enter selection are merged internally, this is not the case in d3v4,v5, which I'll show below.*

```js
var button = d3.select("button")
  .on("click", function() {
    update(random());
  })
  
var svg = d3.select("div")
  .append("svg");
  
var color = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([0,0.5,1])
  .range(["red","orange","yellow"])
  
update(random());

function update(data) {
    var rows = svg.selectAll("g")
        .data(data);
 
    // enter new rows where needed
    rows.enter()
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", function(d,i) {
        return "translate("+[0,i*22]+")";
      })
       
    // Select all rects:
    var rects = rows.selectAll("rect")
      .data(function(d) { return d; })

    // Enter new rects:
    rects.enter().append("rect")

    // Update rects:
    rects.attr("fill", function(d) {
        return color(d);
      })
      .attr("x", function(d,i) { return i*22; })
      .attr("width", 20)
      .attr("height", 20);
 
 
    console.log("entered rows:" + rows.enter().size());
    console.log("entered rects:" + rects.enter().size());

}

function random() {
  return d3.range(5).map(function() {
    return d3.range(5).map(function() {
      return Math.random();
    })
 })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js"></script>
<button>Update</button>
<div></div>
```

**v4/v5**:

For v4/v5, which I suggest upgrading to, the pattern is a bit different as you have to explicitly merge the enter and update selections:

```js
var button = d3.select("button")
  .on("click", function() {
    update(random());
  })
  
var svg = d3.select("div")
  .append("svg");
  
var color = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0,0.5,1])
  .range(["red","orange","yellow"])
  
update(random());

function update(data) {
    var rows = svg.selectAll("g")
        .data(data);
 
    // enter new rows where needed
    rows = rows.enter()
      .append("g")
      .merge(rows)  // merge with existing rows
      .attr("transform", function(d,i) {
        return "translate("+[0,i*22]+")";
      })

    // Select all rects:
    var rects = rows.selectAll("rect")
      .data(function(d) { return d; })

    // Enter new rects:
    rects = rects.enter().append("rect")
      .merge(rects);

    // Update rects:
    rects.attr("fill", function(d) {
        return color(d);
      })
      .attr("x", function(d,i) { return i*22; })
      .attr("width", 20)
      .attr("height", 20);
 
}

function random() {
  return d3.range(5).map(function() {
    return d3.range(5).map(function() {
      return Math.random();
    })
 })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<button>Update</button>
<div></div>
```

**Update**

Your snippet almost incorporates the changes, but you still need to break up the second selection, that of the rectangles, so that you enter new rectangles and then update all of them:

```js
var csv = "'3, 6, 0, 8'\n'1, 9, 0, 4'\n'3, 0, 1, 8'\n'4, 0, 2, 7";
csv = csv.replace(/'/g,'');

var button = d3.select('button')
    .on('click', function() {
        createHeatmap(update());
    });

var w = 120;
var h = 120;
var intensity = 10;
var margin = {
    top: 25,
    right: 25,
    bottom: 25,
    left: 25
};

var svg = d3.select('#heatmap')
    .append('svg')
    .attr('width', w + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr('height', h + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append('g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')');

createHeatmap(csv); 

function createHeatmap(csv) {
    console.log(csv);
    var data = d3.csv.parseRows(csv).map(function(row) {
        return row.map(function(d) {
            return +d;
        });
    });

    var min = 0;
    var max = d3.max(data, function(d, i) {
        return i + 1;
    });
    var rectSize = 30;

    // define a colorScale with domain and color range
    var colorScale = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0,0.5,1])
        .range(['red', 'green', 'blue']);

    // append group of svg elements bound to data
    var rows = svg.selectAll('g')
        .data(data);

    // enter new rows where needed
    rows.enter().append('g');

    // select all rects
    var rects = rows.selectAll('rect')
        .data(function(d, i, j) {
            return d;
        });

    // enter new rects:
    rects.enter().append('rect');
    
    // CHANGES HERE:
    // Broke chain so that update actions aren't carried out on the enter selection:
    rects.attr('x', function(d, i, j) {
            return (i * rectSize);
        })
        .attr('y', function(d, i, j) {
            return (j * rectSize);
        })
        .attr('width', w / max)
        .attr('height', h / max)
        .style('fill', function(d, i, j) {
            return colorScale(d * intensity);
        });
}

function update() {
    var data = "'0, 1, 9, 5'\n'4, 0, 7, 2'\n'6, 3, 0, 8'\n'5, 3, 7, 0";
    data = data.replace(/'/g,'');
    return data;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js"></script>
<button>Update</button>
<div id="heatmap"></div>
```

Comment: Andrew, thanks for the response. I tried your first suggestion, modifying your example to fit my data, but it resulted in an empty graph. I'll post my changes in a answer as tis edit will. not allow me to do so...

Comment: @MikeJames You should be able to update the question with the changes (answers used to clarify often get flagged for removal) - and if you could create a snippet that shows the problem as a minimal example, it might be easier to show a solution.

Comment: I don't know how to add a snippet...sorry.

Comment: @MikeJames, you can add a snippet when editing the question - there is an icon in the text editor that inserts a snippet (looks like: < > ).  From there you can add javascript, html, etc. It's not the best editor, you could link to something like js fiddle or a github repo if that is easier (if it's short, I'll bring it into the question as a snippet).

Comment: Actually, I added a new bug, since fixed and update my OP. The code is working now in that a get the heat map, but it is not updating when I send new data. I'll have to come up with a snippet as I figure out how to do it...thx!

Comment: I added a snippet that closely represents what I am doing and shows the update issue.

Comment: Andrew, was my snippet helpful?

Comment: @MikeJames Haven't had a chance to look just yet, will later today though.

Comment: @MikeJames, Took a look, you were close, just needed to separate enter and update for rectangles, same as you did for rows.

Comment: Andrew, this is awesome, thanks for helping me out. I'll need to study this a bit more to fully understand how/why you break the method chain the way that you have done.